# taking weighted average of a list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a vector of `weight` and a list of the same length as `weight`. I want to calculate
the weighted average of each element of the list using the `weight` as shown below:

```
wt <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)      
temp_ls <- list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(5, 6, 7, 8), z = c(9, 10, 11, 12))

result_vec <- rep(length(temp_ls$x))
   
for(i in seq_along(temp_ls$x)){
  
   temp_vec <- rep(NA, length(temp_ls))
    
   for(j in seq_along(temp_ls)){
      
     temp_vec[j] <- temp_ls[[j]][i]
      
   }
    
  result_vec[i] <- weighted.mean(temp_vec, wt)
}


result_vec
# 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6
```

This approach seems way too complicated and long and wondered if any shorter method is there
using `lapply` family.

Comment: I think this is a case where life would be easier using a different data structure, _i.e._ one where the values to be operated on are grouped in rows or columns instead of split across vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to `transpose` the `list`, loop over the `list` and apply the `weighted.mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
temp_ls %>%
     transpose %>%
     map_dbl(~ weighted.mean(flatten_dbl(.x), w = wt))
#[1] 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6
```

---

Or another approach would be to `enframe` the `list` to a two column tibble, then `unnest` the `list` element and do a group by `weighted.mean`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
enframe(temp_ls) %>% 
  mutate(wt = wt) %>%
  unnest(c(value)) %>% 
  group_by(grp = rowid(name)) %>% 
  summarise(out = weighted.mean(value, w = wt), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pull(out)
#[1] 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6
```

---

Or using `aggregate` after `stack`ing into two column data.frame in `base R`

```
aggregate(values ~ grp, transform(stack(temp_ls), 
   grp = ave(seq_along(ind), ind, FUN = seq_along)),
      FUN = weighted.mean, w = wt)
# grp values
#1   1    4.6
#2   2    5.6
#3   3    6.6
#4   4    7.6
```

---

Or using `mapply`

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = function(...) weighted.mean(c(...), w = wt), 
     unname(temp_ls)))
#[1] 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6
```

Or with `Map`

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) weighted.mean(c(...), 
            w = wt), unname(temp_ls))))
```

---

Or more compactly

```
apply(do.call(cbind, temp_ls), 1, weighted.mean, w = wt)
#[1] 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6
```